# XSLT to convert xml into another structure

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, visual-studio-2012

This is my response structure that i am getting

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetPrice_HotelResponse xmlns="PricingAirAPI">
            <GetPrice_HotelResult xmlns:a="PricingHotelAPI" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Error i:nil="true" />
                <a:Results xmlns:b="PricingCommonAPI">
                    <b:HotelSearchResult>
                        <b:AmountAfterTax>561.9600</b:AmountAfterTax>
                        <b:AmountBeforeTax>561.9600</b:AmountBeforeTax>
                        <b:B2B2BHotelPrice xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HotelB2B2BPricingEngine">
                            <c:AgentMarkUp>0</c:AgentMarkUp>
                            <c:SubAgentMarkUp>0</c:SubAgentMarkUp>
                        </b:B2B2BHotelPrice>
                        <b:BookingSource>JacTravel</b:BookingSource>
                        <b:CityId i:nil="true" />
                        <b:CityName i:nil="true" />
                        <b:CountryCode i:nil="true" />
                        <b:Currency>GBP</b:Currency>
                        <b:Discount>0.00</b:Discount>
                        <b:HotelCode>12035</b:HotelCode>
                        <b:HotelName i:nil="true" />
                        <b:HotelSupplierResultType>None</b:HotelSupplierResultType>
                        <b:IsUniversalApiResult>true</b:IsUniversalApiResult>
                        <b:Price xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TekTravel.Hotel.PricingEngine">
                            <b:AccPriceType>NetFare</b:AccPriceType>
                            <b:AdditionalTxnFee>0.0</b:AdditionalTxnFee>
                            <b:AgentCommission>0</b:AgentCommission>
                            <b:AgentCommissionRate>0</b:AgentCommissionRate>
                            <b:AgentIncentiveAmt>0.00</b:AgentIncentiveAmt>
                            <b:AgentIncentiveRate>0.00</b:AgentIncentiveRate>
                            <b:AgentMarkUp>0</b:AgentMarkUp>
                            <b:AgentMarkUpAmt>0.0000</b:AgentMarkUpAmt>
                            <b:AgentMarkUpType>Percentage</b:AgentMarkUpType>
                            <b:AgentPLB>0</b:AgentPLB>
                            <b:AgentPLBRate>0</b:AgentPLBRate>
                            <b:AirlineBaggageCharges>0</b:AirlineBaggageCharges>
                            <b:AirlineMealCharges>0</b:AirlineMealCharges>
                            <b:AirlineSeatCharges>0</b:AirlineSeatCharges>
                            <b:AirlineTransFee>0</b:AirlineTransFee>
                            <b:CateringCharge>0</b:CateringCharge>
                            <b:CessTax>0</b:CessTax>
                            <b:ChargeBU />
                            <b:CommissionType>RB</b:CommissionType>
                            <b:ConvenienceCharges>0</b:ConvenienceCharges>
                            <b:Currency />
                            <b:CurrencyCode>INR</b:CurrencyCode>
                            <b:DealId>0</b:DealId>
                            <b:Discount>0</b:Discount>
                            <b:EduCessAmount>0</b:EduCessAmount>
                            <b:EduCessRate>0</b:EduCessRate>
                            <b:FareBreakdown i:nil="true" />
                            <b:IsGPEnabled>false</b:IsGPEnabled>
                            <b:IsOurServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>false</b:IsOurServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>
                            <b:IsOurServiceTaxOnComm>false</b:IsOurServiceTaxOnComm>
                            <b:IsServiceChargeApplicable>true</b:IsServiceChargeApplicable>
                            <b:IsServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>false</b:IsServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>
                            <b:Markup>80</b:Markup>
                            <b:NetFare>0</b:NetFare>
                            <b:OtherCharge>0</b:OtherCharge>
                            <b:OurCommRate>0</b:OurCommRate>
                            <b:OurCommission>0</b:OurCommission>
                            <b:OurCommissionType>RB</b:OurCommissionType>
                            <b:OurEduCessAmt>0</b:OurEduCessAmt>
                            <b:OurEduCessRate>0</b:OurEduCessRate>
                            <b:OurIncentiveAmt>0</b:OurIncentiveAmt>
                            <b:OurIncentiveRate>0</b:OurIncentiveRate>
                            <b:OurPLB>0</b:OurPLB>
                            <b:OurPLBRate>0</b:OurPLBRate>
                            <b:OurPlbType i:nil="true" />
                            <b:OurServiceTaxAmt>0</b:OurServiceTaxAmt>
                            <b:OurServiceTaxRate>0</b:OurServiceTaxRate>
                            <b:OurTdsCommAmt>0</b:OurTdsCommAmt>
                            <b:OurTdsIncentiveAmt>0.0</b:OurTdsIncentiveAmt>
                            <b:OurTdsPLBAmt>0</b:OurTdsPLBAmt>
                            <b:OurTdsRate>0</b:OurTdsRate>
                            <b:PlbType i:nil="true" />
                            <b:PrfCurrency i:nil="true" />
                            <b:PrfROE>0.0</b:PrfROE>
                            <b:PriceId>0</b:PriceId>
                            <b:PublishedFare>0</b:PublishedFare>
                            <b:RateOfExchange>1</b:RateOfExchange>
                            <b:ResultId>0</b:ResultId>
                            <b:ReverseHandlingCharge>0</b:ReverseHandlingCharge>
                            <b:SegmentFee>0</b:SegmentFee>
                            <b:ServiceTaxRate>0</b:ServiceTaxRate>
                            <b:SeviceTax>0</b:SeviceTax>
                            <b:StockType />
                            <b:SupplierId>0</b:SupplierId>
                            <b:TDSPLB>0</b:TDSPLB>
                            <b:Tax>0</b:Tax>
                            <b:TaxBreakup i:nil="true" xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
                            <b:TdsCommission>0</b:TdsCommission>
                            <b:TdsIncentive>0.00</b:TdsIncentive>
                            <b:TdsRate>0</b:TdsRate>
                            <b:TotalGP>0</b:TotalGP>
                            <b:TransactionFee>0</b:TransactionFee>
                            <b:WLCharge>0</b:WLCharge>
                            <b:WLPrice i:nil="true" />
                            <b:WhiteLabelDiscount>0</b:WhiteLabelDiscount>
                            <b:YQTax>0</b:YQTax>
                            <c:DynamicPriceAgentComm>0</c:DynamicPriceAgentComm>
                            <c:DynamicPriceOurComm>0</c:DynamicPriceOurComm>
                        </b:Price>
                        <b:RateType>Negotiated</b:RateType>
                        <b:RoomDetails />
                        <b:TotalGP>0</b:TotalGP>
                    </b:HotelSearchResult>
                    <b:HotelSearchResult>
                        .....
                    </b:HotelSearchResult>
                </a:Results>
                <a:Status>Successful</a:Status>
                <a:TraceId>b748e818-5c6a-4e41-94ca-f8552a328b99</a:TraceId>
            </GetPrice_HotelResult>
        </GetPrice_HotelResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now I want to create xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfHotelSearchResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <HotelSearchResult>
    <ResultIndex>1</ResultIndex>
    <HotelCode>AMB3|LON</HotelCode>
    <HotelName>Ambassadors Bloomsbury</HotelName>
    <HotelCategory />
    <StarRating>FourStar</StarRating>
    <HotelDescription>***Special Offer Free welcome gift for stays of 4 or more nights and free bottle of water in each room </HotelDescription>
    <HotelPromotion />
    <HotelPolicy />
    <HotelPicture>http://images.gta-travel.com/HH/Images/GB/LON/LON-AMB3-1.jpg</HotelPicture>
    <HotelAddress>12 UPPER WOBURN PLACE London WC1 0HX United Kingdom, , United Kingdom, </HotelAddress>
    <HotelContactNo />
    <Latitude />
    <Longitude />
    <AmountBeforeTax>0</AmountBeforeTax>
    <AmountAfterTax>0</AmountAfterTax>
    <AmountBeforeDiscount>0</AmountBeforeDiscount>
    <AmountBeforeTaxInSupplierCurr>259.00</AmountBeforeTaxInSupplierCurr>
    <AmountAfterTaxInSupplierCurr>259.00</AmountAfterTaxInSupplierCurr>
    <AmountBeforeDiscountInSupplierCurr>259.00</AmountBeforeDiscountInSupplierCurr>
    <BookingSource>GTA</BookingSource>
    <CurrencySupplier>GBP</CurrencySupplier>
    <PreferredROE>0</PreferredROE>
    <IsBaseCurrencyRequired>false</IsBaseCurrencyRequired>
    <Price>
      <CommissionType>RB</CommissionType>
      <PlbType>RB</PlbType>
      <OurPlbType>RB</OurPlbType>
      <AirlineTransFee>0</AirlineTransFee>
      <TdsCommission>0</TdsCommission>
      <TDSPLB>0</TDSPLB>
      <PriceId>0</PriceId>
      <PublishedFare>0</PublishedFare>
      <NetFare>0</NetFare>
      <Markup>0</Markup>
      <ServiceTax>0</ServiceTax>
      <CessTax>0</CessTax>
      <OurCommission>0</OurCommission>
      <OurPLB>0</OurPLB>
      <AgentCommission>0</AgentCommission>
      <AgentPLB>0</AgentPLB>
      <OtherCharges>0</OtherCharges>
      <Tax>0</Tax>
      <WhiteLabelDiscount>0</WhiteLabelDiscount>
      <TransactionFee>0</TransactionFee>
      <Currency>INR</Currency>
      <ChargeBU />
      <AccPriceType>PublishedFare</AccPriceType>
      <RateOfExchange>0</RateOfExchange>
      <AdditionalTxnFee>0</AdditionalTxnFee>
      <WLCharge>0</WLCharge>
      <Discount>0</Discount>
      <ReverseHandlingCharge>0</ReverseHandlingCharge>
      <YQTax>0</YQTax>
      <IsServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>false</IsServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>
      <TdsRate>0</TdsRate>
      <AgentMarkUpType>Percentage</AgentMarkUpType>
      <AgentMarkUp>0</AgentMarkUp>
      <AgentMarkUpAmt>0</AgentMarkUpAmt>
      <ConvenienceCharges>0</ConvenienceCharges>
      <PrfROE>0</PrfROE>
      <ServiceTaxRate>0</ServiceTaxRate>
      <EduCessRate>0</EduCessRate>
      <EduCessAmount>0</EduCessAmount>
      <AgentCommissionRate>0</AgentCommissionRate>
      <AgentPLBRate>0</AgentPLBRate>
      <AirlineBaggageCharges>0</AirlineBaggageCharges>
      <AirlineMealCharges>0</AirlineMealCharges>
      <AirlineSeatCharges>0</AirlineSeatCharges>
      <OurCommRate>0</OurCommRate>
      <OurPLBRate>0</OurPLBRate>
      <OurIncentiveRate>0</OurIncentiveRate>
      <OurIncentiveAmt>0</OurIncentiveAmt>
      <SegmentFee>0</SegmentFee>
      <OurCommissionType>RB</OurCommissionType>
      <OurServiceTaxRate>0</OurServiceTaxRate>
      <OurServiceTaxAmt>0</OurServiceTaxAmt>
      <OurEduCessRate>0</OurEduCessRate>
      <OurEduCessAmt>0</OurEduCessAmt>
      <OurTdsRate>0</OurTdsRate>
      <IsServiceChargeApplicable>true</IsServiceChargeApplicable>
      <OurTdsCommAmt>0</OurTdsCommAmt>
      <OurTdsPLBAmt>0</OurTdsPLBAmt>
      <IsGPEnabled>false</IsGPEnabled>
      <TotalGP>0</TotalGP>
      <CateringCharge>0</CateringCharge>
      <AgentIncentiveRate>0.00</AgentIncentiveRate>
      <AgentIncentiveAmt>0.00</AgentIncentiveAmt>
      <TdsIncentive>0.00</TdsIncentive>
      <DealId>0</DealId>
      <SupplierId>0</SupplierId>
      <StockType />
      <IsPaidByAgentCreditCard>false</IsPaidByAgentCreditCard>
      <AmountPaidByAgentCreditCard>0.00</AmountPaidByAgentCreditCard>
      <OurTdsIncentiveAmt>0.00</OurTdsIncentiveAmt>
      <IsOurServiceTaxOnComm>false</IsOurServiceTaxOnComm>
      <IsOurServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>false</IsOurServiceTaxOnBaseFarePlusYQ>
      <ServiceFee>0</ServiceFee>
      <TotalTxnFee>0</TotalTxnFee>
      <SwachhBharatCessRate>0</SwachhBharatCessRate>
      <SwachhBharatCessAmount>0</SwachhBharatCessAmount>
    </Price>
    <RateType>Negotiated</RateType>
    <CityName />
    <IsDomestic>false</IsDomestic>
    <NoOfRooms>0</NoOfRooms>
    <NoOfNights>0</NoOfNights>
    <IsTBOMapped>false</IsTBOMapped>
    <SupplierHotelCodes />
    <UAPISessionId>7685eeea-c903-4eb7-ae76-2369f40b635c</UAPISessionId>
    <HotelDetails>
      <StarRating>All</StarRating>
    </HotelDetails>
    <BookingMode>NotSet</BookingMode>
  </HotelSearchResult>
  <HotelSearchResult>   
   .......
  </HotelSearchResult>  
</ArrayOfHotelSearchResult>
```

Can anybody help me in making xslt. Currently I an unable to get any value in xslt and i am also facing problem in debugging in VS2012. Sometimes debugger comes sometimes not.

Comment: Please provide an example of your stylesheet. There's a a bunch of namespace in here, it maybe related to that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        const string XML_INPUT = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument inputDoc = XDocument.Load(XML_INPUT);
            List<XElement> hotelSearchResults = inputDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "HotelSearchResult").ToList();
            XNamespace aNS = hotelSearchResults[0].GetNamespaceOfPrefix("a");
            XNamespace bNS = hotelSearchResults[0].GetNamespaceOfPrefix("b");

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>" +
               "<ArrayOfHotelSearchResult xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
               "</ArrayOfHotelSearchResult>";


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement arrayOfHotelSearchResult = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (XElement hotelSearchResult in hotelSearchResults)
            {
                XElement newHotel = new XElement("HotelSearchResult");
                arrayOfHotelSearchResult.Add(newHotel);
                newHotel.Add(new object[] {
                    new XElement("ResultIndex", ++count),
                    new XElement("HotelCode", (string)hotelSearchResult.Descendants(bNS + "HotelCode").FirstOrDefault())
                });
                XElement price = new XElement("Price");
                newHotel.Add(price);
                price.Add(new XElement("CommissionType", (string)hotelSearchResult.Descendants(bNS + "CommissionType").FirstOrDefault())); 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Using XmlReader

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        const string XML_INPUT = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XML_INPUT);
            XNamespace bNS = "PricingCommonAPI";
            while(!reader.EOF)
            {
                if(reader.Name != "HotelSearchResult")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("HotelSearchResult", bNS.NamespaceName);
                }
                if(!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement hotelSearchResult = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hi i already using similar code which works fine but my xml size is too high sometimes around (6-8 mb) so XDocument.Load(XML_INPUT) takes too much time in such scenario. I found xslt is much faster in such cases. thats why i want to do this using xslt.

Comment: For huge xml files you need to use XmlReader.  I added additional code to my posting showing how to use XmlReader with Linq.

Answer (score -1):

XSLT is a type of stylesheet primarily used to present the data from XML in a human-readable way, usually by putting it into HTML elements.

If you want to convert your existing XML to a new structure, I suggest you use XML tools in C# to deserialize the XML, map it to the new structure and render a new XML.

Comment: XSLT can be used to transform XML to another structure. It's not specifically used to provide a human-readable version of it - even if it is a most common usage.

Comment: Of course, HTML is XML. I'm sorry. What have you tried so far? Please update question with xslt sample.

Comment: I am afraid you couldn't be more wrong. XSLT is a language designed specifically for transforming XML from one schema to another as well as to HTML and plain text. And, at least in my experience, it's most common usage is to bridge between two systems - with no concern for human-readability other than as a bonus. (And no, HTML is not XML.)

Comment: I stand corrected. I will make sure to do more research before answering in the future. Thank you for the critique!